# Cannot find a match for a positive lookforward (?=pattern) example in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

When I am learning assertion in regex, my friend gives me a pattern 
`/one(?=two)three/`
ask me to find a valid string that matches it. However, It seems that it's impossible to find such a string. "onetwothree" is not valid. I try to explain it that `(?=xxx)` takes no actual character, so this pattern has no match. But it is still kind of confusing. Hope someone could verify it thoroughly. :-)

Comment: that matches one=two>three, you need parens not <>

Comment: that fixed regex would be impossible,  because it can't match two and three at the same time.  use regex101.com lets you test the regex and explains matches in detail

Comment: the website saves me! thx@user120242

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the site https://regex101.com which allows playing and testing your regex, and gives you a very detailed explanation of how your regex is functioning.

Your regex will always fail, because it is impossible to match both two and three at the same time.
You can see in this screenshot of the regex debugger, after it tests for the positive lookahead for "two", it starts matching again from the position at the beginning of two and tries to match three, which fails.

[image: match step 9]

Animated recording of the regex matching shown through the regex101 debugger:

[image: animated match step recording]

Answer (score 0):

abstraction: the regex is really

```
onethree
   ^
(?=two)
```

the `^` points to the position where `(?=two)` is inserted as a check.
as seen looking ahead is a `three` so it is never a `two`
and the whole regex will always *fail*.

changing the regex to `one(?=two).*?three` will match onetwothree